# unordered_map, no match function call error

Tags: c++, boost, unordered-map

The example program of `unordered_map` when I run in Linux terminal using `c++11 or c++17`, it works fine. I tried the same program in `eclipse` `Neon.1a Release(4.6.1)` using `c++11 or c++17`, gives many error messages including

> > no matching function for call to ‘boost::unordered::unordered_map >::insert(int, std::pair)’
> >        refmap.insert(1, std::make_pair(2,5));

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>
#include <utility>
typedef boost::unordered_map<int, std::pair<int, int> > reference_map;
reference_map refmap;
int main(){

        refmap.insert(1, std::make_pair(2,5));
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`insert` takes a single argument, not two – a `std::pair<K const, V>` (aka `std::unordered_map<K,V>::value_type`):

```
int main() {
    refmap.insert(std::make_pair(1, std::make_pair(2, 5)));
}
```

The function taking separate arguments for key and value is named `emplace`, and should be preferred in most cases:

```
int main() {
    refmap.emplace(1, std::make_pair(2, 5));
}
```

<kbd>**[Online Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9cc8cd8ad2fd70d0)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, yeah rightly said, but why it works in linux terminal